# Can "maxAge" of "org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory" impact active database connection

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc, tomcat8

This is what is our PROD scenario:

- We are using `org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory` and having maxAge of `900000` and `maxActive` of `100`.
- We have long database operation and it is failing because of database connection closed exception.
- When I checked the logs then I found that this exception is occurring after ~15 minutes.

So, this makes me wonder if this is because of `maxAge` of `900000`. I read the docs of Apache and other blogs but no where I could find a clear answer whether `maxAge` will impact an active database connection or not.

From the docs only thing I am 100% sure of is that `maxAge` is checked when moving a database connection in or out of the pool, but I not sure on what happens once database connection is in use...

Has anyone having similar experience with this or knows if `maxAge` impacts an active connection or not?

---

UPDATE 1:

I am using Tomcat 8.5

Comment: Before you roll back the tag edit again: Please explain what this question has to do with [tag:apache]. [Tag Info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/apache/info)

Comment: @OlafKock: why you are trying to remove "apache" tag from my question.. this issue is specific to Apache as you can see I have mentioned the class - org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory... please leave it be...

Comment: @OlafKock please check my above comment

Comment: well, read the "Tag Info" that I've linked above, please.

Comment: @OlafKock: ok understood, won't rollback.. but still I feel if we had this then my question would have got better visibility.. going by with a rule book in hand doesn't always help..

Comment: With the tag, your question would have better visibility _among people who care about the Apache httpd server_, but not at all about your topic. With the same reason you could also tag it "PHP": Better visibility, but simply irrelevant. Feel free to find other relevant topics that might be prefixed with "apache" though. There are plenty

Comment: @OlafKock: can't argue on the logic... added Tomcat because this is specific to Tomcat server as well..

Comment: good choice. Without answering: Have you tried doubling or quadrupling `maxAge` and check if it indeed has an effect on your long running operations? I'd have expected the value to be relevant for handing out connections from the pool as well, but I'm not aware if there's a background clean-up job going on, for example. You might also want to add which _exact_ version of Tomcat you're working on (there are also tags for it, but the complete version number is welcome)

Comment: @OlafKock: till now I have tried to reproduce in the local environment by reducing `maxAge` to 1 minutes and I can see ~1 minute I start getting database connection closed exception.. so I am inclined to believe that `maxAge` has impact on active database connection, but it is hard to believe because nowhere in the official docs this is mentioned, so want experts to look into it and comment.. let me check which Tomcat version we are using..

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://people.apache.org/%7Efhanik/jdbc-pool/jdbc-pool.html) it will not close your connection that's already in use. It rather checks for the age before returning it to the pool - after you released the connection. And closes if max age has elapsed.
We went from no-max-age to 10 minutes and didn't see the issue you're reporting.

From the documentation,

> When a connection is returned to the pool, the pool will check to see
> if the now - time-when-connected > maxAge has been reached, and if so,
> it closes the connection rather than returning it to the pool.